# php date conversion to date having time

Tags: php, date-conversion

I am trying to convert php date conversion like 09/30/2011 to this format 2011-09-30 21:35:46.

I read some manuals but its going to be difficult for me.

```
$input = "09/30/2011";
$output = "2011-09-30 21:35:46";

$output = date('Y-m-d h:m:s', strtotime($input))
```

Comment: What's not working here?

Comment: You code works fine. As no time specified in original format it prints current time. What time do you need?

Comment: my format was wrong Y-m-d h:m:s should be Y-m-d h:i:s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format string 'Y-m-d h:m:s' should be modified to 'Y-m-d H:i:s' in your code.
In `date` function, the format char 'm' is month, not minute; and 'h' is hour from 01 to 12, 'H' is hour from 00 to 23.

Comment: Man, I really don't believe that. After more than 10 years of PHP and wondering why my script is not working....You saved my day. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your code works but if you want to play around with the DateTime in PHP here is a little example.

Every date output except a timestamp needs a timezone to get the right time in that timezone.

So, if your php config dosen't already set it up for you, set your default timezone by:

```
date_default_timezone_set('XXXX');
```

XXXX stand for a value out of the [List of supported timezones](http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)

If you want to use your date as an object you need to initialize it now by:

```
$date = new DateTime();
```

$date will now have the current time, if you want to set a time in your example "09/30/2011" you can do this directly by writing:

```
$date = new DateTime('09/30/2011');
```

To format the date output you can use this:

```
echo $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Or if you want to set your time as well you can initilize the DateTime with a time as well:

```
$date = new DateTime( '09/30/2011 21:35:46' );
```

Always keep in mind that the formated output depends on your timezone.

To read more about DateTime look at the [DateTime class manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php).